# Error building cordova ionic app in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build in Visual Studio 2017 an Ionic app in IOS remoted device but I get an error.

**I have selected 6.3.1 and I get this error:
Remote build error from the build server https://xxxx.xxxxx.com:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version.**

To solve it I follow all this questions but the I couldn´t solve it:

[Install specific version of Cordova CLI in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202885/install-specific-version-of-cordova-cli-in-visual-studio-2017)

[Visual Studio 2017 iOS Build Failed to acquire Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090042/visual-studio-2017-ios-build-failed-to-acquire-cordova)

[Error building ios vwith cordova toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775385/error-building-ios-vwith-cordova-toolset) I have the same error than this question but I tried the solution and for me does not work.

So finally I have selectedGlobal 7.1.0 in the config.xml and then I get the following error:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error   MSB4018 Error inesperado en la tarea "VsTac".
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'.
>   Nombre de archivo: 'C:\myuser\eazanza\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'
>      en System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      en System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>      en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.AppAsTgzStream(String changeTimeFile, JObject lastChangeTimesMap)
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
>      en Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
>      en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() MyApp   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets 256

Could someone help me?

Comment: Check the version of the IOS platform you have in your project.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but I'm on the same boat. I've been struggling with this issue for a week already with no results. As your exception is localized in Spanish I'd like to add a screenshot of the English version here: i.stack.imgur.com/l4utc.jpg Also you can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/46202885/496676

Comment: My ios cordova version is 4.2.0 but I need 4.3.0 and I can´t update it

Comment: @Eri-Ka my advice is to give up on VS2017 and install VS2015.

Comment: @Eri-Ka Read this page and the latest comments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation